# Get a city with the Cloudflare IP geolocation

Tags: geolocation, cloudflare

In the [docs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-Configuring-IP-geolocation), I see I can get a Country, but is there a way to get a bit more, like a subdivision or even a city, from Cloudflare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare users on **Business** or **Enterprise** plans have access to more granular geolocation fields in the Ruleset Engine (which powers many different Cloudflare features)

- `ip.geoip.subdivision_1_iso_code`: Represents the ISO 3166-2 code for the first level region associated with the IP address.
- `ip.geoip.subdivision_2_iso_code`: Represents the ISO 3166-2 code for the second level region associated with the IP address.

See this [documentation page](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ruleset-engine/rules-language/fields/) for the full list.

Comment: It's worth noting that **all** users have access to the [Managed Transforms Rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/managed-transforms/reference/), of which one option _Add visitor location headers_ adds various headers with location information.